# Retaining input box value after alert

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a form where input box has some default text. When user clicks the input box, i want the text to be clear which onfocus handles. However i am also alerting user if they have entered over 140 chars. But after alert the text changes to null again. TO handle this i tried setting some flag still not working.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input
        type="text"
        maxlength="140"
        name="question"
        value=" What's your Question?"   
        onfocus="this.value = '';
            this.style.color = 'black';
            this.style.fontStyle = 'normal';
            if(refreshFlag) {
                this.value = askQues;
            }"
        onkeypress="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
                var askQues = this.value;     
                var refreshFlag = true;               
                alert('Please use less than 140 characters to ask question');
                this.value = askQues;
            }"                 
        style="color: black; font-style: normal;"
    />
</form>
```

Code also at Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gQSc/

Comment: What is the purpose of storing `this.value` in a variable before alert and setting it back after alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine on Firefox 20.0.1

Why don't you use the [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute for the input field?

Comment: It will only display "Ask a question" if there is no text, then you can remove the whole onfocus attribute. Otherwise you could add a check in the onfocus event to see if the text is NOT "Ask a question".

Comment: @CodeMonkey Beware of browser support for `placeholder` http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Comment: Almost all modern browsers support placeholder. There are javascript plugins for IE8 and lower to support it though.
Example: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Comment: does chrome on iPhone support that ?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is the scoping issue. 
You are creating 2 variables, **askQues** and **refreshFlag**  which are declared inside the handler. So they are not accessible outside the scope of the function.

Move those up into the window context .And also it is a better idea to move the logic to inside the script tag, or better into a javascript file. Replace the inline with styles.. It would be a lot cleaner..

Try this

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="question" 
              placeHolder="What's your Question?" class="inputInactive"/>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.inputInactive{
    color: black;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    var refreshFlag;
    var askQuestion;
    $('input[name="question"]').on('focus', function () {
        this.value = '';
        if (refreshFlag) {
            this.value = askQues;
        }
    });

    $('input[name="question"]').on('keypress', function () {
        if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
            askQues = this.value;
            refreshFlag = true;
            alert('Please use less than 140 characters to ask question');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gQSc/5/)**

Comment: i know that. i mentioned it in my question itself. problem is how can i save the value

Comment: i wish i could set your answer as best one. But i got a simplified solution. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign that text as the value for an input of the `hidden` type.

Comment: Sure thing. Using jQuery: `$("#hiddenText").val(askQues);`. You'd use this right after the the alert, and you need an `<inpyt type="hidden" id="hiddenText">`. In order to fetch the value later: `$("#hiddenText").val();`

Answer (score 0):

Check my version below, I simplified by using `onblur` function with a condition check. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9euwq/

```
<input type="text" maxlength="140" name="question" value="What's your Question?" 
     onfocus="if(this.value == 'What\'s your Question?') { this.value = ''; this.style.color='black'; this.style.fontStyle='normal'; }" 
     onkeypress="if (this.value.length==this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
                        alert('Please use less than 140 characters to ask question'); }" 
     onblur="if (this.value === '') { this.value = 'What\'s your Question?' }" 
     style="color: black; font-style: normal;">
```

**Note:** Try moving the script code inside `<script></script>` tags or an external js. Inline js are hard to debug, maintain and also messy.